# Friedmann Equations with varying G?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, quantum-gravity

If Newton's constant $G$ actually varies with cosmological time $t$ would a suitably modified form of the Einstein field equations:

$$G_{\mu \nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu \nu} = \frac{8 \pi G(t)}{c^4} T_{\mu \nu},$$

together with the standard cosmological assumptions, lead to equations that look like the standard Friedmann equations but with the varying function $G(t)$ in place of the constant $G$?

Comment: Why don't you try to investigate? Do you know how the Friedmann equations are usually derived?

Comment: Not really no. You're right I should investigate myself but I'm lazy. Maybe I'll try to find some cosmology lecture notes online that might give me some clues.

Comment: Energy conservation + Einstein's equations is the way to go. I found that Carroll's book on General Relativity did a good job at explaining it.

Comment: Note that this ansatz breaks energy conservation.  The reason Einstein picked the equation he did was because $\nabla_{a}\left(R^{ab} - \frac{1}{2}Rg^{ab}\right) = 0$, which satisfies the flux requirement on the stress-energy tensor, $\nabla_{a}T^{ab} = 0$.  If you make $G$ a function of spacetime coordinates, you break this.  Also note that this is similar to the approach taken by Brans-Dicke theory, where $G$ is promoted to a scalar field, and is given its own dynamics.  Brans-Dicke has been heavily constrained by solar system observations.

Comment: But is it acceptable for the global energy scale to change with cosmological time so that $G$ is a function of cosmological time alone? This might not imply a breakdown of local energy conservation.

Comment: @JohnEastmond: yes it does.  that gradient includes a time derivative.  if the time derivative of $G$ is nonzero, then you either have to abandon the gradient of $T_{ab}$ being zero, which is unphysical, or you have to modify Einsteins' equation.  Brans and Dicke did the latter, and that theory is observationally ruled out.

Comment: Could G remain constant but the definition of energy changes globally with cosmological time? In that case G itself would not have an explicit time dependence - only the energy units themselves change.

Answer (score 1):

The Friedmann equations are differential equations for the scale factor $a(t)$. You can derive them by plugging in the Friedmann metric $$ds^2=dt^2-a^2\left(\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2}-r^2d\Omega^2\right)$$ where $d\Omega^2=d\vartheta^2+\sin^2\vartheta d\varphi^2$ into the Einstein equations you posted above.

Since the gravitational constant only enters in front of the energy momentum tensor, no derivatives of $G$ occur throughout the derivation. Therefore you can just use the standard Friedmann equations and put $G=G(t)$.

Comment: Note that if you take this approach, it just amounts to rescaling the values of $\rho(t)$ and $P(t)$ by a factor of $G(t)$