# Brans Dicke gravity - are there Friedmann equation equivalents?

Tags: cosmology, newtonian-gravity

I was studying the Brans-Dicke theory of gravity, where the gravitational "constant" is not constant in time, and varies, as $\frac1G=\phi(t)$, meaning that Newton's force law becomes $$\ddot x(t)=-\frac M{\phi(t) x(t)^2}$$I then read a derivation of the derivation of the Friedmann equation, and it involved integrating this force law. However one of the steps used the fact that $G$ was constant to integrate it. I don't know how to do this when using a time-dependent $G$. The example I worked with was $\phi(t)=C t^\alpha$, with $C$ a constant.

My question was - is it possible to integrate this to get equations that are "like" the Friedmann equation? If yes, how can I get to the solution? If no, why not?

Disclaimer: I haven't yet studied General Relativity, as is mentioned in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110925/friedmann-equations-with-varying-g?rq=1) question. Is it possible to do this without GR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Friedmann equations are derived by making the *ansatz*,

$$ds^2 = dt^2 - a(t)^2(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$$

with no factors of $G$ in the metric, and thus the Einstein tensor contains no derivatives of $G$. Then we can write the Friedmann equations with simply $G \to G(t)$:

$$\left(\frac{\dot a}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{8\pi G(t)\rho + \Lambda }{3}, \quad \frac{\ddot a}{a} = -\frac{4\pi G(t)}{3}\left( \rho + 3p\right) + \frac{\Lambda}{3}.$$

You could use these now to solve for $a(t)$ when $G = \mathrm{const}$, and when $G(t)$ is some given function, to see the difference on the scale factor.

---

**Example: matter-dominated universe**

Suppose we consider a matter-dominated universe with $p = 0$. In such a case combining the two equations gives us $2\ddot{a}a + \dot a^2 = 0$ which has as its solution $a(t) \propto t^{2/3}$, with $\rho \propto t^{-2}$.

In certain theories we have $G \propto \phi^2$ for some scalar field, so taking your proposal we can try $G\propto t^{\alpha}$ which leads us to the same equation, with $a(t) \propto t^{2/3}$ but with energy density $\rho \propto t^{-(2+\alpha)}$.